# Company description on SE SoundCloud page is out of date

Tags: bug, soundcloud

Looks like it's been a while since anyone updated the number of SE sites in company description on the [SE SoundCloud page](http://soundcloud.com/stack-exchange/dropbox/profile#).

> Stack Exchange is a fast-growing network of **48** question and answer sites

As of today (12 June 2013) the number of SE sites is up to 104 according to the [SE home page](https://stackexchange.com/).